# Gradle build with Groovy 2.3 throws NoClassDefFoundError due to missing dependency org/apache/tools/ant/BuildLogger

Tags: ant, groovy, gradle

In my gradle build, I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.1'
    runtime 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4'
}
```

When I use Groovy 2.2, everything works fine. With 2.3, I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class groovy.util.AntBuilder due to missing dependency org/apache/tools/ant/BuildLogger
```

I don't know what changed from Groovy 2.2 to 2.3 that involved Ant, but something's gone.

Comment: Is this a runtime error? If so, how do you run the app? Via an IDE? Via gradle? Inside a web-app?

Comment: It happens during the compile-groovy stage of a gradle build from the command line, when I have a script that instantiates an AntBuilder.

Comment: This likely means that you need a `compile` dependency on Ant.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Niederwieser said, switching ant to a compile dependency works:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.9.4'
}
```

That fixes the problem. I don't know why that's necessary under Groovy 2.3 when it wasn't under Groovy 2.2, but so be it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's strange if it wasn't necessary in 2.2, as Ant has always been an optional dependency of `groovy-all` (i.e. not pulled in by default).